# Flask Safe text rendering user generated block

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, jinja2

Currently coding a bbs-style app, I'm wondering what are the best practices to display text that user entered safely. Which means I don't want them to type javascript or things like that. For now I'm rendering in a pre, and forbid the "<" and ">" chars. Though I guess it is not the right way to do it. Plus the lines are cut while it shouldn't.

Could you please give me some hints on how to that ?

More informations : I'm storing those posts in a sqlite db using flask-sqlalchemy. So I don't want them to contain SQL-Injection (which I highly doubt it is possible to do with sqlalchemy)

Comment: SQLAlchemy will prevent you from MOST SQL Injection attacks, since you're probably going to use the expression API or the ORM. However, SQLAlchemy does have chinks in its armor: it allow you to call raw SQL, so you could still end up with SQL injection if you end up trying to use user-submitted info to create your own raw SQL query to run with, for example, the `execute()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the Jinja2 templates as set up by Flask, all content is auto-escaped by default for HTML characters; see [Jinja2 setup](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#jinja-setup) in the templating documentation:

> Unless customized, Jinja2 is configured by Flask as follows:
>
> - autoescaping is enabled for all templates ending in `.html`, `.htm`, `.xml` as well as `.xhtml`
> - a template has the ability to opt in/out autoescaping with the `{% autoescape %}` tag.

SQLAlchemy, used properly, indeed protects you from SQL injection attacks.

If you want newlines in user input to be translated to `<br/>` tags in the HTML output, you can use this [Flask Snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/28/) that adds a Jinja2 tag filter that does just that; translate newlines in an input variable into `<br/>` tags in the rendered output, while still escaping everything else. Multiple newlines are translated to `<p>` paragraph tags.

Add that snippet as a module to your project, make sure it is imported, then use the `nl2br` filter in your templates:

```
User text as paragraphs with line breaks:<br/>
{{ user_text | nl2br }}
```

Comment: I would only add a bit of a disclaimer about how SQLAlchemy prevents you from SQL Injection attacks as long as you use it correctly: it's still possible to use SQLAlchemy without the ORM or expression API, and if you do raw executes without bind parameters, it will not save you.

Comment: @MarkHildreth: amended to 'used properly'. In the context of Flask-SQLAlchemy, most users use it the way Django uses their ORM; for relatively simple queries only.

Answer (score 1):

Jinja's autoescape is turned on by default in Flask.  Anything not explicitly marked safe will be escaped correctly.

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/templating/#controlling-autoescaping

Answer (score 1):

I use Bleach - http://bleach.readthedocs.org/ to strip HTML and only let through the tags I want to allow.  It's really easy to use.